# Forward button click: how to manage with HTML5 history API?

Tags: javascript, html

I've been trying to get the HTML5 history API to work and it seems fairly straightforward, but I can't get it to work with the browser's forward button.

The basic concept *seems* simple: when you go to a new 'page' (via AJAX, javascript, etc) use pushState to save, in the state field of the passed object in the first parameter save the information you will use to recreate that state.  Then put a listener on popState and you can grab the information back and recreate your state.

Thus when I move forward in my app via internal buttons

```
    history.pushState({ myTag: true, div:theDiv }, null, event.target.href);
```

When I move backwards in my app via internal buttons

```
    event.preventDefault();
    history.back(1);
```

And the popState listener is

```
if (!e.originalEvent.state || !e.originalEvent.state.myTag) return;
var theDiv = $('#' + e.originalEvent.state.div);
```

The popState listener works fine when moving backwards internally or via the browser back button.  But moving forward with the browser's forward button I get NULL for e.originalEvent.state -- can someone explain to me what I'm missing and/or the basic conceptual framework?  Much appreciated!